# How to solve a fraction of imaginary numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, systems-of-equations, computational-complexity

[image]I have the following equation.

$a = \frac{(1/2) - (3/2)i}{(3/2) + (3/2)i}$

The solution says that $a^2 = 5/9$.

I don't know how I can perform the steps, could I get some feedback?

Thanks!

Comment: It's pretty clear that $a$ is not a real number, hence $a^2$ can't be $\frac 59$.  Anyway, to simplify the fraction, first multiply numerator and denominator by $2$.

Comment: Just multiply nominator and denominator with $3/2- 3i/2$ to obtain $a^2=\frac{c+di}{9}$ with certain $c,d$.

Comment: Are you sur you've posted the correct value for $a$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the latter first:
$$\frac{\frac12-\frac32 i}{\frac32+\frac32i}=\frac{\frac12}{\frac32}\frac{1-3i}{1+i}=\frac13\frac{(1-3i)(1-i)}{(1+i)(1-i)}$$
Can you proceed?

Comment: Yes, from here I could proceed ! It is part of numerical analysis. I found out that the modulus should be 5/9. Thanks for the help.